# ionic 7, capacitor 5 network issue

Tags: firebase, capacitor, ionic7

I've just upgraded to ionic7 and capacitor5. In my application I'm using firebase. I see this error.

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.9.0): Could not reach Cloud
> Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times.  Most recent error:
> FirebaseError: [code=unavailable]:  The operation could not be
> completed
> This typically indicates that your device does not have a  healthy
> Internet connection at the moment.  The client will operate in offline
> mode until it is able to  successfully connect to the backend.

My dependencies are:

```
"dependencies": {

    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.2.3",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^17.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^17.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^17.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^17.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^17.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^17.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^17.2.4",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/email-composer": "^6.6.0",
    "@capacitor-community/http": "^1.4.1",
    "@capacitor-firebase/messaging": "^5.4.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "^4.2.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "^5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/core": "^5.7.2",
    "@capacitor/device": "^5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/filesystem": "^4.1.5",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "^5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^4.0.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^5.0.8",
    "@capacitor/network": "^5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/push-notifications": "^5.1.1",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^5.0.7",
}
```